# Generating set for the space of real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space, and $T : V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation, then I can determine the action of $T$ on all of $V$ given the action of $T$ on a basis of $V$. Similarly, if $G$ is a group, and $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism, then determination of how $\phi$ acts on a generating set of $G$ allows me to determine how $\phi$ acts on all of $G$, and a similar fact is true of algebras and their homomorphisms.

I would like to apply the above reasoning to the following problem. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the space of functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and consider the evaluation map
$$ e_x : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad e_x(f) = f(x).$$
The question I am considering is: what is a minimal subset $G \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that, if I know how $e_x$ acts on all $g \in G$, then I can deduce $e_x(f)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$. It seems obvious to me that, I need only know how $e_x$ acts on the identity function $\text{id} \in \mathcal{F}$, given by $\text{id}(y) = y$, since then I can recover $x$ from $e_x(\text{id})$ via
$$e_x(\text{id}) = \text{id}(x) = x, $$
from which I can then evaluate $f(x)$ for all $f$. My questions then are:

1. Does $\mathcal{F}$ form an algebraic structure which is generated by the identity function $\text{id}$? The best I can come up with is that $\mathcal{F}$ forms an associative unital algebra, but this is not sufficient since $\text{id}$ only generates the polynomials in $\mathcal{F}$, and this leaves out almost everything in $\mathcal{F}$.
2. Assuming there is an answer to 1., does $e_x$ form a homomorphism of said algebraic structure from which the argument "since $\mathcal{F} = \langle \text{id} \rangle$, and I know $e_x(\text{id})$, I can deduce $e_x(f)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$" follows?